# org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Column 'pacientId' cannot be null

Tags: java, hibernate

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I have the next tables:

[image]

And the entities:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Pacients.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Pacients p")
public class Pacients implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int pacientId;

    private String name;

    private String surname;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to DetaliiPacient
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "pacient")
    @Cascade(value = { CascadeType.ALL})
    private PacientsDetails pacientDetail;

}

@Entity
@Table
@NamedQuery(name = "PacientsDetails.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM PacientsDetails d")
public class PacientsDetails implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int pacientDetailsId;

    private String address;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "pacientId",referencedColumnName="pacientId")
    @Cascade(value = { CascadeType.ALL})
    @JsonBackReference
    private Pacients pacient;
}
```

The field "pacientId" from "pacients" table is AUTO_INCREMENT and I'm using mysql database.

The error from title appears when I'm doing:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(pacient);
```

In logs I see that Hibernate is doing:

```
Hibernate: insert into Pacients (doctorId, name, surname) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into PacientsDetails (address, pacientId) values (?, ?)
```

but the problem is the fact that in the second query the value of pacientId (which is brand new generated by first query) is not recognized.

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: First of all a patient (doctor's client) is written "patient", not "pacient". 2nd: could you please post the code where you save the two entities?

Comment: Thank you for the your answer.  First I had the entities in romanian language and after I did a refactor for using english and I forgot the "Pacient" entity  :)  anyway from technically point of view I solved the problem as I described below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you're creating your entity like this (I know that the fields are private but let's pretend they aren't)

```
pacient = new Pacients();
// set name & surname
pacient.pacientDetail = new PacientsDetails();
// set address
```

If that's the case, you need to set the pacients field in the pacientsDetails as well, because PacientsDetails is mapping the relation, according to your mappedBy

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "pacient")
```

so it should look like this

```
pacient = new Pacients();
// set name & surname
pacient.pacientDetail = new PacientsDetails();
// set address
pacient.pacientDetail.pacient = pacient;
```

Comment: My input is mapped automatically from a json. Anyway I marked your answer as a correct one because you put me on the right track. I had to create the setter in the following way(by setting also the fild "pacient" from "pacientDetail") :                                                                       public void setPacientDetail(PacientsDetails pacientDetail) {
  this.pacientDetail = pacientDetail;
  this.pacientDetail.setPacient(this);
 }

Answer (score 0):

do flush() after persist()

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(patient);
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
...
patientDetails.setPatientId(patient.getId());
...
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(patientDetails);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but seems my problem was what @SergeiBednar suggested.